# Scrollbar positioning, cross browser

Tags: html, css, overflow

In IE, scrollbars appear on the inside of a div - which you could argue is the correct solution. Other browsers, e.g. Chrome, place the scrollbars on the outside of the content.

If I want to always a vertical scrollbar visible for the div, as below:

```
<div style="height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll;">
  <div style="height: 200px; width: 100%; background: #DDD;"></div>
</div>
```

In IE; because there is a vertical scrollbar, it means the scrollbar is hiding some content behind it and shows a horizontal scrollbar to see the content (and then shows there is vertical content to scroll to to make up for the new scrollbar!). In Chrome, the vertical scrollbar pushes the content in, so that there is no hidden content and therefore, the horizontal scrollbar does not appear.

[image]

I want all content visible. Is there a simple cross browser way to get the scrollbars to display consistently?

Ultimately, I have a 100% width table and I just want to scroll it vertically with a fixed height.

---

I am running in IE7 standards, IE8 seems to deal with scrollbars the same as Chrome etc..

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the width of the table, so that it won't exceed the length of the scroll bar.

I generally think it's just a problem with the way IE works.